# What is the mvn command (CLI) to add a Maven Central hosted JAR into your local .m2 repository

Tags: java, maven, jar, repository

I have an **.m2** repository, like so (a fragment):

```
[ ... ]
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0/carbonite-1.4.0.jar.lastUpdated
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0/carbonite-1.4.0.jar.sha1
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0/carbonite-1.4.0.pom.lastUpdated
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0/carbonite-1.4.0.jar
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0/carbonite-1.4.0.pom
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0/_remote.repositories
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/carbonite/1.4.0/carbonite-1.4.0.pom.sha1
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5/chill-java-0.3.5.pom.sha1
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5/chill-java-0.3.5.jar.sha1
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5/chill-java-0.3.5.jar
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5/chill-java-0.3.5.pom
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5/chill-java-0.3.5.pom.lastUpdated
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5/_remote.repositories
/home/user/.m2/repository/com/twitter/chill-java/0.3.5/chill-java-0.3.5.jar.lastUpdated
[ ... ]
```

And, using the UNIX/LINUX **mvn CLI**, I similarly want to add an entry for a new JAR that is hosted at Maven Repository or Maven Central (or wherever these things are hosted online) to my local **.m2** repository. For example, let's say I want to add this one locally (which is hosted at mavenrepository.com):

```
-DgroupId=com.codahale
-DartifactId=metrics-graphite
-Dversion=3.0.2
```

What is the **mvn** command (CLI) to do this?

Note: I found instructions for adding 3rd party JARS files, etc., but not for this simple case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maven Dependency plugin does that with [the 'get' goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/get-mojo.html). Make sure you're using the latest version by using the fully qualified name:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:get \
    -Dartifact=groupId:artifactId:version
```

You shouldn't need to indicate the repository since it will look into the central repository by default.

Comment: Ah okay, the plug-in part was missing or not the latest (and therefore problematic). The above CLI you provided worked (a method I prefer to Eclipse doing it). Side note for others: to get the latest plug-in version, click on the 'get' goal link provided in the answer. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution to get an particular artifact is to define it as a dependency and simply run your build via `mvn clean package`. Maven will automatically download the artifact.